# get string between characters sed

Tags: sed

I have a string

> abc\xyz\file.txt#4 - blah blah blah

I want the file number so I did the following -

> abc\xyz\file.txt#4 - blah blah blah | sed -e "s/[A-Z,a-z,\,/,.#:,-/s]//g"

It gives the expected output - 4

But when the string is -

> abc\xyz1\file.txt#4 - blah blah blah | sed -e "s/[A-Z,a-z,\,/,.#:,-/s]//g"

It gives the output as - 14.

So I was trying to get string between '#' and '-'
I tried -

> abc\xyz1\file.txt#4 - blah blah blah |sed 's/^.*# //; s/-.*$//'

but it only works when there is space before #, which is not true in this case.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
sed 's/.*#\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

This searches for everything up to and including the `#, followed by zero or more numbers, followed by the remainder of the line. So the search string matches the entire line.

It then replaces the matching pattern (that is, the entire line) with the part that matches the sub-pattern between the escaped parens, which is the <strike>droid</strike> number you're looking for.

To print only the matching lines, use

```
sed -n 's/.*#\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

where the `-n` flag suppresses the default behavior of printing every line, and the `p` suffix prints the matching lines.

Comment: Is it possible to combine it with "grep"? Your script would print non-matching lines as they are. I would like non-matching lines to be ignored.

Comment: Yes; I've updated the answer to include the command that will print only matching lines. Sorry it took 8 months.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
echo "abc\xyz1\file.txt#4 - blah blah blah" | sed -e "s|.*#||g" -e "s| -.*||g"
```